# Hosting SQLite DB on Azure Storage?

Tags: sqlite, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

I need to host an SQLite database on Azure that will be shared among several web apps. My only options seem to be Azure Blob or File Storage (since they got rid of the "Azure Websites" that provided dedicated storage shared among web instances). However, there does not appear to be any way to map an Azure Storage share to a drive that the Web App will recognize, and thus no way to generate a path that SQLite can use. And obviously, SQLite can't use REST APIs to access the DB without tremendous hacking in the SQLite VFS.

So I'm wondering if anyone has successfully hosted an SQLite DB on Azure Storage such that it was accessible to a Web App?

Comment: What do you mean, "they got rid of the Azure Websites?" It was simply renamed to Web Apps (a loooong time ago). And you absolutely still have shared durable storage there. (durable as long as you don't delete your web app deployment, that is)

Comment: My understanding was that all storage on App Services that is not part of the actual site that you upload was to be considered temporary and could be lost at more or less any time. Is that not the case?
In any event, my storage requirements would be in the gigabytes likely so that is still not an option.

Comment: Nope not the case. Unless you delete the deployment, the shared disk area is durable. Also: Standard tier offers 50GB, and premium offers 250GB. (VM local disks, on the other hand, are truly temporary).

Comment: Ohh, hmm. That might actually be workable then (the 250 at least). Ok I am totally looking in the wrong places then. I'm sorry I find the Azure stack extremely confusing. Would you be so kind as to point me to the right info on the MS site? Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Azure Web Apps (formerly known as Web Sites) still exists, and still has durable, shared storage across your web app instances.

You cannot use a blob to hold SQLite, as it is not compatible with file I/O (it has a REST API for access). And you cannot simply attach an Azure File Storage volume (you *can* use one, via API, but cannot mount it to an Azure Web App instance).

Nothing's changed with Web Apps: just place your SQLite database in a directory underneath your app's root directory.

Comment: Ok. I had found info (which now I of course can't locate) that seemed to suggest File Storage, if not Blob Storage, might be an option and was trying to see if any one had tried it successfully. It sounds like without making a custom SQlite VFS (which I have done before, but which is horrifically painful) that would make the REST API calls, it's just not possible. Shame they don't let you connect Web Apps to File Storage through SMB/UNC. Anyway thanks for helping to clarify the persistent storage issue at least.

Comment: "just place your SQLite database in a directory underneath your app's root directory.". Right. But how can another Azure Web App access this same sqlite database that is placed under, say App1's root directory under app_data folder?

Comment: All instances of a web app share the same file storage. If you launch a completely different web app, that new web app and its instances gets its own file storage.

Comment: And that's exactly the problem. Incidentally my solution is to make a dedicated database service on top of sqlite that will be accessed by the other web apps. Very frustrating that we can't mount azure storage to web apps.