# Publish webapp in Azure with SQLite db

Tags: sqlite, azure

I have a project with SQLite DB. I want to publish it on azure, the application itself is published, but the database is not transferred. How to correctly import my database to azure?

Comment: Take a look at utilities like: [SpecticalCore](https://www.spectralcore.com/fullconvert/howto/sqlite-to-sqlazure) and [easyfrom](https://www.easyfrom.net/articles/sqlite_to_azure/)

Comment: have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43547953/7073340)

Comment: "Just at the place of its database." SQLite in the directory under the root directory of your application ". And where on the portal to see where the database is now located? In the visual studio project, the database file is already in the root folder.